# Doubt about Bulirsch's proof for Cholesky decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, cholesky-decomposition

I was reading the Bulirsch and Stoer's Introduction to Numerical Analysis proof for the Cholesky decomposition, you can find a copy [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U3bwbC0WJxDmINxEhpBxrmUwBAkU7ayX/view?usp=sharing), and I got stuck.

My problem is that, in my opinion, there's a point in this proof where it uses a false argument. Shortly, in the proof we have a positive-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ and we are looking for a lower triangular matrix $L$ which satisfies $L·L^* = A$. With this objective, we write
$$
L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\widetilde L & 0\\
c^* & \alpha \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
such that
$$
L\cdot L^*=
\begin{pmatrix}
\widetilde L\cdot\widetilde L^* & \widetilde Lc \\
c^*\widetilde L^* & c^*c+\alpha^2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\widetilde A & b \\
b^* & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
=A
$$

We know $\widetilde L$ exists because of the induction hypothesis and $c^*$ exists because $\widetilde L$ is nonsingular, so $\widetilde Lc =b$ has a unique solution. Therefore, we need only find an $\alpha$ such that $c^*c +  \alpha^2 = a_{nn}$, $\space \alpha > 0$. However, to show that such an $\alpha$ exists, this is to say, to show that $a_{nn} - c^*c>0$, it argues that $\det(A) = |\det(\widetilde L)|^2\alpha^2 > 0$, and therefore $\alpha^2 = a_{nn} - c^*c>0$. To me, this argument is invalid because it is first supposing that such an $\alpha$ exists, otherwise we couldn't decompose $\det(A)$ in such a way, and under that assumption it follows that $\alpha^2>0$, but it is precisely that very assumption that we want to show is true, so I don't understand how simply supposing it does the job.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very well written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the authors' argument is invalid. One may prove that $a_{nn}>\|c\|^2$ by using the positive definiteness of $A$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&<\pmatrix{c^\ast \widetilde{L}^{-1}&-1}
\pmatrix{\widetilde{A}&b\\ b^\ast&a_{nn}}
\pmatrix{(\widetilde{L}^\ast)^{-1}c\\ -1}\\
&=\pmatrix{c^\ast \widetilde{L}^{-1}&-1}
\pmatrix{\widetilde{L}\widetilde{L}^\ast&\widetilde{L}c\\ c^\ast\widetilde{L}^\ast&a_{nn}}
\pmatrix{(\widetilde{L}^\ast)^{-1}c\\ -1}\\
&=\pmatrix{c^\ast \widetilde{L}^{-1}&-1}
\pmatrix{0\\ \|c\|^2-a_{nn}}\\
&=a_{nn}-\|c\|^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
A different but closely related approach is to consider the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) $S$ of $\widetilde{A}$ in $A$. Since $A$ is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to $\widetilde{A}\oplus S$, the Schur complement $S$ must be positive. Now the result follows from the fact that $S=a_{nn}-b^\ast\widetilde{A}^{-1}b=a_{nn}-\|c\|^2$.